# Can we use adapter for custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have AddressCustomView in which I want to show a list of states in drop down list.
Can we use adapter for custom view ? I wonder if it's the right way ?

Here is what I am trying:

Custom view:

```
public class AddressCustomView extends BaseCustomView {

private StateListAdapter mStateListAdapter;

public AddressCardView(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull StateListAdapter stateListAdapter) {
    super(context);
    this.mStateListAdapter = stateListAdapter.
}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class StateListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State> {

private List<State>  mStateList;

public StateListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<State> stateList) {
    super(context);
    this.mStateList = stateList;
 }
}
```

Comment: sure you can. But the adapter only generates a cell for given index, so you have to implement placing cells into your view manually. Also why can't you use a ListView?

Comment: Thanks @VladyslavMatviienko, actually I have to use existing adapter which has been already implemented.